# How to access the fields of a custom node variable in a custom Rules event?

Tags: 7, rules

I have created a custom Rules event, following the instructions in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/215857/16550 The event provides a custom node variable:

```
function MYMODULE_rules_event_info() {
  return array(
    'my_event' => array(
      'label' => t('My custom event'),
      'group' => t('My group'),
      'module' => 'MYMODULE',
      'variables' => array(
        'my_variable' => array('type' => 'node', 'label' => t('This is a node')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

As expected, the variable *my-variable* shows up in the available tokens in a new Rule. I would now like to modify a field called *Integer* of the *my-variable* node, so I tried adding the conditions

- Entity is of type: Quiz result answer
- Entity has field: field_integer

However, I still cannot access `my-variable:field_integer` in any Rules actions. How can I do that?

**Note**: As the first Rules condition suggests, my variable *my-variable* is actually a Quiz result answer, provided by the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module. I don't think it is related to the problem, but one never knows for certain...